# How to pass (save) installation directory chosen while running installer (Inno Setup)

Tags: inno-setup

I am using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org) to make a setup.exe file for my Windows desktop application. It works well.

One problem is:
User is able to choose the installation directory while running the setup.exe.

My Windows application should know that information to adjust its directory structure.

Can you let me know how I can pass the selected installation directory into other outside file or registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you install the application to the installation directory.

And the application knows where it is run from.

For example in C# you can use:

```csharp
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

So you do not need to pass the location anywhere. You already have that information.

---

Anyway, to write the installation path to the registry, use:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; ValueType: string; \
    ValueName: "InstallationPath"; ValueData: "{app}"
```

---

Or you can run the application at the end of the installation with some custom parameter specifying the new path, to let the application do the stuff (possibly silently):

```
[Run]
FileName: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Parameters: "/InstalledTo=""{app}"""; Flags: postinstall
```

Though again, note the redundancy. The path is already in the application path (`{app}\MyProg.exe`), no need to pass it again (in `Parameters`).

Comment: Thanks. While running setup.exe, user can choose any directory information and Application doesn't know about it. That's why I need to pass that information somewhere. I think the way using Registry would be a workaround. But it would work on only Windows. Can I pass it anywhere?

Comment: Do you mean that the application must do something about changed directory during the installation? It's not really clear what you aim to do. Only on Widows: Inno Setup works on Windows only. So it's not a limitation. Pass where? Another option is to run the application, passing the directory on command-line, see my edit.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. I think we can run any small program after setup.exe is done. Great.  Thank you so much!!!